# independent variables or not

Tags: probability

I have $X$ and $Y$ that are independent random variables, I define $Z_1=X-Y$ and $Z_2=X+Y$. Why $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent as well? Not clear to me at all as I see, say X in both variables, so don't they share a clear "dependency" then between each other? Thanks for any pointers how to show it!

Comment: Who told you that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are indeed independent? If $X=c$ a.s. then automatically $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but $c-Y$ and $c+Y$ are not necessarily independent. Maybe you are confusing independent with uncorrelated.

Comment: Have you left out words such as "normal" or "identically distributed" in writing your assertion about independence?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: from aboove I see the statement is in fact incorrect, would that make a difference if $X$ and $Y$ are iid?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are iid (and have finite variance), then $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are _uncorrelated_ random variables. However, they are not necessarily independent random variables. If _in addition_, you are told that $X$ and $Y$ are _normal_ random variables, then $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are not just uncorrelated -- they are _independent_ random variables. In summary, independence is not sufficient to make $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ independent; finite and identical variance (not necessarily independent nor necessarily identically distributed) makes $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ uncorrelated.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I think they are Normal and independent in fact. Although I am not sure why the sum and difference are independent in that case. If $X$ and $Y$ are normal and indpnt, then $X+Y$ is also normal, so as $X-Y$, why the last two are independent then?

Comment: See [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/112692/6633) on stats.SE for an answer to "Why are the last two..."

Answer (score 1):

How about rolling an ordinary six-sided fair die twice; $X$ is value of first roll; $Y$ is value of the second roll.  If you knew, say, that $Z_1=X-Y=5$, does that give you any information about $Z_2=X+Y$?

If knowing information about one random variable changes your assessment of probabilities for the other random variable, then the variables are not independent.

Comment: Yes if the first die has only one face.

Comment: @drhab I was thinking of ordinary six-sided dice.  Answer was showing by example that having information about $Z_1$ could affect the probabilities for $Z_2$.

Comment: Then I misunderstood you. I withdraw my downvote. Sorry, somehow I can only withdraw it after an edition.

Comment: Some editing will enable me to withdraw my downvote. So the "ball is on your side" now.

Comment: @drhab, thanks for the input.  I did some edits.  How does it look?

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $f_Xf_Y=f_{XY}$.

Consider now $f_{Z_1Z_2}=\frac 12f_{XY}\left(\frac{z_2+z_1}{2},\frac{z_2-z_1}{2}\right) .$ Then $f_{Z_1}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 12 f_{XY}\left(\frac{z_2+z_1}{2},\frac{z_2-z_1}{2}\right)dz_2$ and similarly $f_{Z_2}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 12 f_{XY}\left(\frac{z_2+z_1}{2},\frac{z_2-z_1}{2}\right)dz_1$.

Now, $f_{Z_1}f_{Z_2}=\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 12 f_{XY}\left(\frac{z_2+z_1}{2},\frac{z_2-z_1}{2}\right)dz_2\right]\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 12 f_{XY}\left(\frac{z_2+z_1}{2},\frac{z_2-z_1}{2}\right)dz_1\right]$.

Consider $f_{XY}=4xy\mathcal X_{[0,1]}(x)\mathcal X_{[0,1]}(y)$ and then try to show that $f_{Z_1}f_{Z_2}\neq f_{Z_1Z_2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample:

If $X$ and $Y$ are both integer random variables, then $(X-Y)$ and $(X+Y)$ are simultaneously odd or even. If you knew, say, that $X-Y$ is odd, then $X+Y$ is odd too, so they are not independent.